# telegraph database creation failed, how to configure ports in mac os for influxdb telegraph

Tags: influxdb

Following the documentation for telegraph v0.13, we try to launch the telegraph instance in terminal:

```
telegraf -config telegraf.conf
```

Note the Database creation failed:

> Get http://localhost:8086/query?db=&q=CREATE+DATABASE+IF+NOT+EXISTS+%22telegraf%22: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8086: getsockopt: connection refused

How to fix? Is it a firewall problem?

The error is visible in the log in the terminal output:

2016/07/27 22:15:11 Starting Telegraf (version 0.13.1)
2016/07/27 22:15:11 Loaded outputs: influxdb
2016/07/27 22:15:11 Loaded inputs: cpu mem
2016/07/27 22:15:11 Tags enabled: host=johns-MacBook-Pro-2.local
2016/07/27 22:15:11 Agent Config: Interval:10s, Debug:false, Quiet:false, Hostname:"johns-MacBook-Pro-2.local", Flush Interval:10s 
2016/07/27 22:15:30 Output [influxdb] buffer fullness: 11 / 10000 metrics. Total gathered metrics: 11. Total dropped metrics: 0.
2016/07/27 22:15:30 Database creation failed: Get http://localhost:8086/query?db=&q=CREATE+DATABASE+IF+NOT+EXISTS+%22telegraf%22: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8086: getsockopt: connection refused
2016/07/27 22:15:30 Error writing to output [influxdb]: Could not write to any InfluxDB server in cluster
2016/07/27 22:15:40 Output [influxdb] buffer fullness: 21 / 10000 metrics. Total gathered metrics: 21. Total dropped metrics: 0.
2016/07/27 22:15:40 Database creation failed: Get http://localhost:8086/query?db=&q=CREATE+DATABASE+IF+NOT+EXISTS+%22telegraf%22: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8086: getsockopt: connection refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, wasn't a port issue. influxdb wasn't running properly